# First order PDE using characteristic equation by hand

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I want to solve this first order PDE using characteristic equation by hand:

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-g(x)\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=0$$ The characteristic equations are:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{dx}{ds}&=1\\[2ex]
\frac{dy}{ds}&=-g(x)\\[2ex]
\frac{dz}{ds}&=0\\
\end{align}
$$

I can solve it if $g(x)=$ a constant. But what if this isn't true i.e., $g(x)\neq a$?!!!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's think for a moment about the problem $u_x  - x u_y = 0$, where I have made $g(x) = x$. Then, the characteristics are given by the relation:

$$ \mathrm{d}x = - \mathrm{d}y/x $$

or, equivalently, $ x \, \mathrm{d}x + \mathrm{d}y = 0$. On integrating, one would find $x^2/2 + y = C$ so $u = f(C)$, where $f$ is an arbitrary function of $C$. What happens for a general $g(x)$ does not differ much from this example except for the fact that the integration of $g(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$ has no simpler form.

Can you take it from here?